# Recreating DataReader from JSON - Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, datareader

I have been struggling with following problem for couple of days, finally I hope You can help me out.

I have a running WebService from which I need to return IDataReader interface which is not serializable (it HAS TO BE DataReader - I know that DataTable or DataSet is serializable but certain requirements force me to use IDataReader) so I serialized it to JSON which can be send without problem but now I need to deserialize json back into DataReader on client side.

Do You guys have any idea how can I acomplish that?

My JSON is serialized to the following format:

```
[
  {
    "Cst_Id": 3,
    "Cst_Name": "Test 1adssad",
    "CtA_Id": 3
  },
  {
    "Cst_Id": 3,
    "Cst_Name": "Test 1adssad",
    "CtA_Id": 8
  },
.....
]
```

Comment: It is impossible to serialize a data reader.  That JSON is meaningless and cannot be converted back into a data reader.

Comment: yeah i think you are going to have some problems with that. Serializing a data reader does not make sense.  I would push back on that requirement.

Comment: DB -> IDataReader -> (serialize) -> JSON -> (deserialize) -> insert into DB -> IDataReader     `Its idiotic and I'll mail you a jar of piss if you do it.. but that's about the only way.`

Comment: Okay, thanks guys - I know that it is really idiotic but that is the only way I could that. I guess I will have to find some way around it.

Can I select comment as answer or should I make new post?

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to use IDataReader, you can use Protocol Buffers DataReader Extensions for .NET to Serialize/Deserialize IDataReader instead of Json.

Protocol Buffers is efficient in WebService.

Example:

```
    string connstring1 = "Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=northwind;user=xxx;password=xxx";

    //Serializing an IDataReader into a ProtoBuf:

    Stream buffer = new MemoryStream();
    using (var c1 = new SqlConnection(connstring1))
    {
       c1.Open();
        // Serialize SQL results to a buffer
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", c1))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            DataSerializer.Serialize(buffer, reader);

        // Deserialize, Read them back
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var reader = DataSerializer.Deserialize(buffer))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["ProductName"]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For details, [Protocol Buffers DataReader Extensions for .NET](https://github.com/rdingwall/protobuf-net-data)